# How to remove a frame from Chrome's devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging a website, and more often than not, I need to quickly inspect some element and do some stuff in the console with jQuery. However, when I inspect element and click on it, the focus in dev-tools jumps to the body of a frame called postmessageRelay.

How do I remove it? Or at the very least block it from grabbing `$0` and `document.activeElement`?

[image: screenshot of the Frame]

Comment: Sounds like a bug that manifests when site isolation is enabled in chrome://flags so simply disable it. You can also switch the context in the toolbar to "top" manually.